# convert money/decimal to string

Tags: .net, formatting

I'm using .net. Is there some code somewhere that can change

$11,456.50 -> eleven thousand four hundred fifty six and 50/100 Dollars

I can do it myself, but don't want to rewrite something that's already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an unpolished first shot. No error checking at all and the code does not handle the fractional part. And it is almost untested. With [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx) the method can handle values up to `10^66 - 1` or about `219` bits easily extended by adding more entries to `M2`.

```
public static String NumberToText(Decimal n)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        return "minus " + NumberToText(-n);
    }
    else if (n == 0)
    {
        return M1[n];
    }
    else
    {
        var scale = 0;
        var parts = new List<String>();

        while (n != 0)
        {
            if (n % 1000 != 0)
            {
                parts.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", NumberToTextSmaller1000(n % 1000), M2[scale]));
            }

            n = Math.Floor(n / 1000);
            scale++;
        }

        parts.Reverse();

        return String.Join(", ", parts.ToArray());
    }
}

private static String NumberToTextSmaller1000(Decimal n)
{
    var pattern = (n < 100) ? "{2}" : (n % 100 == 0) ? "{0} {1}" : "{0} {1} {2}";

    return String.Format(pattern, M1[Math.Floor(n / 100)], M1[100], NumberToTextSmaller100(n % 100));
}

private static String NumberToTextSmaller100(Decimal n)
{
    return (0 <= n) && (n < 20)) || (n % 10 == 0) 
        ? M1[n] 
        : String.Format("{0}-{1}", M1[n - n % 10], M1[n % 10];
}

private static readonly IDictionary<Decimal, String> M1 = new Dictionary<Decimal, String>
    {
        { 0, "zero" }, { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }, { 3, "three" },
        { 4, "four" }, { 5, "five" }, { 6, "six" }, { 7, "seven" },
        { 8, "eight" }, { 9, "nine" }, { 10, "ten" }, { 11, "eleven" },
        { 12, "twelve" }, { 13, "thirteen" }, { 14, "fourteen" },
        { 15, "fifteen" }, { 16, "sixteen" }, { 17, "seventeen" },
        { 18, "eighteen" }, { 19, "nineteen" }, { 20, "twenty" },
        { 30, "thirty" }, { 40, "forty" }, { 50, "fifty" }, { 60, "sixty" },
        { 70, "seventy" }, { 80, "eighty" }, { 90, "ninety" }, { 100, "hundred" }
    };

// The leading spaces are important.
private static readonly IDictionary<Decimal, String> M2 = new Dictionary<Decimal, String>
    {
        { 0, String.Empty }, { 1, " thousand" }, { 2, " million" }, { 3, " billion" },
        { 4, " trillion" }, { 5, " quadrillion" }, { 6, " quintillion" },
        { 7, " sextillion" }, { 8, " septillion" }, { 9, " octillion" },
        { 10, " nonillion" }, { 11, " decillion" }, { 12, " undecillion" },
        { 13, " duodecillion" }, { 14, " tredecillion" }, { 15, " quattuordecillion" },
        { 16, " quindecillion" }, { 17, " sexdecillion" }, { 18, " septendecillion" },
        { 19, " octodecillion" }, { 20, " novemdecillion" }, { 21, " vigintillion" }
    };
```

Called on `Decimal.MaxValue` the method returns the following.

seventy-nine octillion, two hundred twenty-eight septillion, one hundred sixty-two sextillion, five hundred fourteen quintillion, two hundred sixty-four quadrillion, three hundred thirty-seven trillion, five hundred ninety-three billion, five hundred forty-three million, nine hundred fifty thousand, three hundred thirty-five

Answer (score 0):

Not, in the .Net framework itself.

You'll need to do it yourself or find an existing implementation online (Google it).

Comment: @Jose: try searching `.NET money formatting` or maybe `.NET currency formatting` or `.NET convert numbers to words` (but then you'd have to apply your own changes for "dollars" and "cents").